# FQL query in Graph API explorer not returning all of the data in profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have created a test user for my facebook app and filled in the fields for name, profile picture, music, tv, movies, books, actvities and interests.  The information is there and I can view it in the profile, but for some reasons in spite of having specified what appear to be the correct permissions, I cannot access this information even through the Grap API explorer when I am logged in as the user.

When I go to the Graph API explorer, go to the FQL tab and launch the following query I only get certain fields:

```
SELECT name,pic_big,music,tv,movies,books,email FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

The response is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Aisha Bibi",
      "pic_big": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/274348_100004159483336_574477135_n.jpg",
      "music": "",
      "tv": "",
      "movies": "",
      "books": "",
      "email": "aisha_gjmodrm_bibi@tfbnw.net"
    }
  ]
}
```

I generated the access token for this request by selecting the following user data permissions:  `email, user_activities, user_education_history, user_interests`.

Could anybody tell me why it is failing to retrieve information for the user even though it is present on the profile, I have detailed the correct permissions(?) and I am logged in as them while accessing the Graph API explorer tool?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry - I did not read the documentation clearly enough it seems.  In order to access the user's music and movies etc you need the `user_likes` permission.  I hope this helps somebody!